Visio Pro 2016 Relative Hyperlink opens another instance when file is saved on network drive
I have a Visio file with a whole lot of relative hyperlinks (all in the same document). When the file is opened from my local machine, and I click on any link, it goes to the section of the document. But when the file is opened from a mapped network drive, with full admin rights, it opens another instance of the same document. I've checked the trust settings, allowed network locations, allowed the full network path, everything. Stumped here

I managed to establish that this issue is related to DFS shares - if the path is \servername\dfs_share\subfolder1\subfolder2 then the above issue occurs. If however I map to the network folder directly and open the file it works as expected. Copying the file to any other non-DFS share delivers the same working result. My question then changes to is this a DFS, Windows or Visio related setting or issue ?
